# Why is this import undefined in some cases?

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I created a minimal React Native project to demonstrate the problem:
https://github.com/allenhsu/ReactNativeImportTest

Try `react-native run-ios` and see the console logs.

There're mainly 4 JS files to check, `index.ios.js`, `common/TestView.js`, `common/colors.js` and `common/index.js`.

In `common/index.js`, I re-exported TestView, and Colors in several ways.

In `index.ios.js`, I imported TestView from `common` module.

In `common/TestView.js`, I imported Colors from `common` module and also directly from `common/colors.js`:

```
import {
  Colors,
  DefaultColors,
} from './';

import AnotherColors from './colors';

console.log('Colors out of component:');
console.log(Colors);
console.log(DefaultColors);
console.log(AnotherColors);

export default class TestView extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Colors in render:');
    console.log(Colors);
    console.log(DefaultColors);
    console.log(AnotherColors);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          I'm a test view.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
Colors out of component:
TestView.js:17 undefined // Colors
TestView.js:18 Object {white: "#FFFFFF", black: "#000000"} // DefaultColors
TestView.js:19 Object {white: "#FFFFFF", black: "#000000"} // AnotherColors

TestView.js:23 Colors in render:
TestView.js:24 Object {white: "#FFFFFF", black: "#000000"} // Colors
TestView.js:25 Object {white: "#FFFFFF", black: "#000000"} // DefaultColors
TestView.js:26 Object {white: "#FFFFFF", black: "#000000"} // AnotherColors
```

My only question is, why the first one is `undefined`? The one imported into `common/index.js` first then exported with name `Colors`.

What's more interesting is, if I change the re-export of `TestView` to:

```
export { default as TestView } from './TestView';
```

The second one, `DefaultColors` out of Component will also be undefined.

**UPDATE**

If I do the same thing in `index.ios.js`, all three variables are defined out of the Component. So I believe it's somehow related to the loop-imports of `common/index.js` and `common/TestView.js`.

Comment: I see this problem with nested import/export modules (index.js imports from another module and exports it).  First got the error with RN 0.45.1 and React 16 alpha 12. Hope someone can give a clue as to what's going wrong.